# "Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault" when changing window

Tags: python, windows, pygame

I'm currently learning python and tried to make a little game using the pygame librabry. I use python 3.2.3 and pygame 1.9.2a with Windows Xp. Everything works fine, except one thing : if I go on another window when my game is running, it crashes and I get an error message in the console :

```
Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
```

This piece of code that I took out of my program seems to be causing the error, however I can't see anything wrong with it :

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

fenetre = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

go = 1

while go:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            go = 0
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Not that it helps with your problem but you could just write `while go:` since anything else than `False/None/0` equals true. But I can't see anything wierd about your code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice anyway ! If this isn't too much asking, could you or anyone else try to run this code to see if it reproduces the error on another computer ? I'd do it myself, but I don't have another computer available right now.

Comment: No problems on windows 7, same python/pygame builds!

Answer (score 4):

I know thread is old, but I was getting the same error "Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault" in linux when I resized a pygame window continuously for several seconds. Just in case this helps anyone else, it turned out to be caused by blitting to the window surface in one thread when I was resizing it in another thread by calling pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size, 0). I fixed it by acquiring a lock before drawing to or resizing the window.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have anything after the last line that you're not putting in, but if you don't, you should replace your last line with

```
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

As an alternative, you could put those two lines outside of the `while` loop and keep what you have.  Don't forget to `import sys`.